# Do not fire 'child_changed' if a certain field is modified

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My application requires a monitoring service which I am hosting on Heroku which monitors, corrects, and modifies data based on changes to the users account. However there are some fields on the users account which are updated at rapid speeds, and having all of these accounts spam my monitoring service with data is very inefficient.

Is it possible to ignore fields when listening to `child_changed` so that the callback is not fired and the data is never downloaded? Depending on the users speed, I could be downloading hundreds of accounts a few times a second on my monitoring application and that's just something that will go down in flames.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
{
    name: 'Jimmy',
    birthday: 'Mar 23, 1976',
    biography: 'Random text',
    interests: {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Perhaps I want to ignore the `biography` field, therefor the `child_added` feature should download new account information ONLY if one of the following values are changed:

- name
- brithdate
- interests

and the data should be ignored and not downloaded if the `biography` field is changed, because it's not a field that is relevant to my monitor, and just wastes bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase always synchronizes complete nodes. If you want to synchronize only a subset of each node from a list of nodes, you should separate that subset into its own top-level node.

```
profiles: {
  uidJimmy:  {
    name: 'Jimmy',
    birthday: 'Mar 23, 1976',
    biography: 'Random text',
  }
},
interests: {
  uidJimmy: {
      // ...
  }
}
```

You'll find this to be a common these when using Firebase (or most other NoSQL databases): you have to model the data for the way that your application wants to consume it. I highly recommend reading this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: This is what we have been doing, I was just wondering if there was a way to normalize the data. Thanks.